# Is OpenId, OAuth, OIDC just a specification?

Tags: authentication

I'm tring to understand OpenID, OAuth etc. Are these protocols or layers are just a specification? Something like unicode. Whereas authentication provider like Active Direcory, KeyCloak, Ping Identity etc. are the software that implement these specification?

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding, hope it helps you clear things a bit

OAuth 2.0 is the industry-standard protocol for authorization
so protocol by definition means "a set of rules governing the exchange or transmission of data between devices."
So yea, this is specification

OpenID is an open standard and decentralized authentication protocol.
OpenID is supposed to clear few missing pieces in Oauth2.0
Again this is a protocol aka set of rules

Now we would need some implementations for this hence we have solutions such as Keycloak, Okta, Auth0